# StoryBoard Navigate to Root View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

This is my first time using story board and I've set up like 5 view controllers with UINavigationController with buttons that push to the next view controller..

So I start on VC1 and push to VC2, then click and button and push to VC3, then click a button and push to VC4, and so on... on the last screen (VC5) I have a "home" button that the user can click to go back to the home screen (VC1), I've set it up so it pushes to VC1, the problem is when the user clicks that they are taken to the homescreen but then there is a back button on the navigation bar and they can go back to the last screen? After they click home they should not be able to return to previous screens without navigating through to them like they had the first time!

How can I accomplish this? Thanks! I'm used to working with xib and programmatically controlling the UINavigationControllers so this StoryBoard stuff is very new to me haha!

Comment: If you don't want the back button, you don't wanna do a `push`, you can either pop all the way back to the controller you want, or just load it up the old fashioned way.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia How do I "pop" in the storyboard file? Or does that have to be done with code? If so, what's the code I can add to my viewController5.m ?

Comment: Both would be through code behind.  Look into `popViewControllerAnimated` on the navigation controller

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I removed the "push" from that button in the storyboard then in my .m file added `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and it only took me back 1 ViewController from VC5 to VC4? How do I "pop" to a specific VC like VC1?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Got it! NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want an unwind segue. On the VC1 .m file add the following blank method:

```
 - (IBAction)unwindToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
 {
 }
```

Then in your storyboard on VC5 Ctrl-drag from your home button to the green Exit button at the bottom of your view controller. Choose the unwindToMainMenu option and it should now go back to the VC1 when pressed and no longer have the back button as it has popped all the view controllers.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked just as good as the answer I had in the comments... maybe even better because this probably frees up any memory that UIViewController may have been storing for previous views in case the user "goes back" to them (even though they can't haha but I'm sure the device doesn't *know* that!)

Comment: I don't have to do anything in the .h right? Only stick this in the .m and be done with it? :)

Comment: Yep, you don't need anything in the .h file (I don't in my project and it works great). Glad it's working for you :)

Comment: I figured there was a better way, thus why I decided not to post as an answer.

Comment: It seems like the VC5 isn't completely gone in my case.. the background music is still playing. Anything we can do to explicitly free VC5 on exit?

Comment: What should we do if i need to perform this action on AlertController OK button ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the method you're looking for is `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```